# responsive columns that slide horizontally

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to create responsive columns. What I want is for when the user clicks the left or right arrows, for the next column of content to slide in from the left or right, depending on whether the user clicked left or right.

I see how to do this with fixed width columns: http://jsfiddle.net/nheldman/GB7Hc/3/

But how do I do it with responsive width columns?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1 arrow"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="country"><a href="">Afghanistan</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Albania</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Algeria</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Andorra</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Angola</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Antigua</a></div>
</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
<div class="country"><a href="">Argentina</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Armenia</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Australia</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Austria</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Azerbaijan</a></div>

</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
<div class="country"><a href="">Bahamas</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Bahrain</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Bangladesh</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Barbados</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Belarus</a></div>
<div class="country"><a href="">Belgium</a></div>
</div>

 (would like to have other columns of countries here)

<div class="col-md-1 arrow"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the demo you provided it animates by fixed `152`

```
$('.table-container').animate({scrollLeft:'+=152'}, 'slow');
```

so your task is on DOM ready and on window resize to keep track of the `col-md-3` width:

```
$(function(){ // DOM IS NOW READY

    var $colMD3 = $('.col-md-3'); // Cache your selector!
    var colW;

    function getColW(){
       colW = $colMD3.outerWidth(true);
    }
    getColW(); // on DOM ready - get the width
    $(window).resize( getColW ); // but also on resize

    // OTHER CODE HERE

});
```

and your clicks than should look like:

```
 // OTHER CODE HERE
 $('#previous-column, #next-column').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var np = this.id.match("next") ? "+=" : "-=" ;
    $('.table-container').stop().animate({scrollLeft: np+colW}, 800);        
 });
```

Comment: The code I attached only works without the bootstrap code. I need something that works with bootstrap rows.

Comment: @LauraNMS Bootstrap rows are all but magic. Please setup a jsbin.com demo and I'll give my best to see how we can do it!

Comment: @LauraNMS sorry, I don't see any columns inside an overflow parent. Unable to help so far